# Retrieve Uploaded Presentation Url using Google Documents API in .NET and C#

Tags: c#, .net, google-docs-api

### **Languages:**

C#
ASP.NET

### **References:**

Google Documents List API for .NET

### **Situation**

I am attempting to produce a web application that takes in an uploaded file (only ppt or pptx extensions) from the application users and uploads it to Google Documents using my Google account. Then retrieves the id of the uploaded document so as to reproduce something like:

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/present/embed?id=" + <%# eval("returnedUploadedId") %> + " frameborder="0" width="410" height="342"></iframe>
```

### **Problem**

However from my tearing away at the Documentation provided on https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#creating_or_uploading_presentations as well as an hour of Googling, it seems that the information is insufficient and lacking for me to refer to and workaround a solution.

I would like to reach out to professionals with .NET, C# and/or Google Documents List API to help me arrive at a point where I can obtain sufficient information to create such an application. Even a provision of some programming logic and relevant resources would be sufficient.

PS: I hope that my question has now overcame the barrier of being vague. I am new to Stack Exchange and even though I have read through the various instructions on posting a good question, I will still require more experience to adequately arrive at a point where I can constantly produce good questions.

Warm Regards,
Gabriel.

Comment: This question has been closed, by a moderator, with no comment or suggestion.  To a seasoned StackOverflow user this is a vague question that lacks research, but to someone with 6 rep and who has only posted twice, this is pretty harsh treatment.  What happened to the [summer of love](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/07/kicking-off-the-summer-of-love/)?

Comment: I have tried searching Google countless of times. I could not manage to find any resources that was sufficiently relevant. Thanks for sympathizing with this newbie though. Moving on, could you suggest a direction I can move towards so that I can make some progress with my research?

Comment: the documentation you linked to seems to contain everything you'd need: it explains how to upload a document, and ends up with a `DocumentEntry` that probably includes the document ID you need.  I'd suggest you break the problem down and approach each stage separately (and ask specific questions on SO if you need help).  Get the sample code compiling, then see what happens, and solve problems one at a time (e.g.: get the document upload working first, *then* worry about getting the ID).  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Dan Puzey! That was great advice.